# Javascript RegExp.prototype.test - how to regex values coming from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to check each values from my array if it matches the string,
however it doesn't work when i'm using `console.log(/^reg_arr[i]/.test(str1));`
but when I use `console.log(/^table/.test(str1));` it works

```js
var str1 = 'table football';
var reg_arr = ["table","football"];
        
for(var i = 0, reg_arr_length = reg_arr.length; i < reg_arr_length; i++)
{
   console.log(/^reg_arr[i]/.test(str1)); /* doesnt work */
}

console.log(/^table/.test(str1)); /* this works */
```

Is there a problem with my syntax,

Thank you,

Comment: I wrote a long answer about how you can create regular expressions from strings, but if you can also change each element in your array into a regular expression by surrounding it with slashes instead of quotes, then get rid of the slashes when testing it. `reg_arr = [/table/]; reg_arr[i].test(str1)`

Comment: Also, the caret (^) at the beginning of your regular expression means match only at the beginning of the string, so `/^football/.test("table football")` would fail, because it's looking for the start of the string, then `"football"`. I don't know if that's intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new RegExp(source: string[, flags: string])` (simply `RegExp(source: string[, flags: string])` is also working)

```js
var str1 = 'table football';
var reg_arr = ["table","football"];
        
for(var i = 0, reg_arr_length = reg_arr.length; i < reg_arr_length; i++)
{
   console.log(new RegExp(`^${reg_arr[i]}`).test(str1));
}
```

Comment: @apelidoko just concat a '^' at the beginning, since we are dealing with string as source now. I modified my code and used a ES6 string interpolation to achieve that, but you can just `'^' + reg_arr[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Using slashes to define a regular expression doesn't allow you to enter variables into the regular expression, that is, in the following example, `str1` is checked to contain `"test"`, not the value of the variable test.

```
var str1 = "hello";
var str2 = "Hello world";
console.log(/str1/i.test(str2))
```

To solve this issue, you need to create a new regular expression for each value in the array, something that can be done with `new RegExp(str)`, instead of slashes.

```
var str1 = "hello";
var str2 = "hello world";
console.log(new RegExp(str1, "i").test(str2))
```

However, this method has a catch, characters from that string are not escaped. So `new RegExp("test.hello")` will match `"test hello"`, because the dot is interpreted as a regular expression wildcard character and not a period. To fix that, we first have to manually escape any special characters in our search string (unless the things `reg_arr` are actually regular expressions). I took the code to do that from the middle of [this MDN page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressionss)

```
var str1 = "hello"
var str2 = "hello world"

str1.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
console.log(new RegExp(str, "i").test(str2))
```

So without changing anything else, your final `console.log` could look like this:

```
console.log(new RegExp(reg_arr[i].replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')).test(str1));
```